# Odd problem with SSRS Background Formatting Expression

Tags: reporting-services, colors, background, formatting, expression

I have applied expression-based background formatting to several fields on a report, but on one field the expression seems to be "hiding" the data in the field while viewing in a browser. The formatting works otherwise.

Example of simple code:

```
=IIf(Fields!ACTNUMST.Value = "15200300", "Yellow", "Transparent")
```

The values are text, not numeric as some of the values passed to that field might contain characters.

What I expect to happen is if the criteria is met, the value 15200300 is visible in the field and the background of that field is Yellow. When the criteria is not met the value 15200300 is visible in the field and the background of that field is Transparent.

What is actually happening is no values are visible in the field while viewing in a browser, however the background color does change based on the criteria.

If I export the report to Excel or PDF, the values are visible. I've tried this in both Chrome and IE and on multiple computers with the same results.

I'm continuing to work through the issue, but it's currently got me stumped.

-Jody

Answer (score 0):

In your expression use `"No Color"` instead of `"Transparent"`.

Comment: Thanks Steven!  I had tried that as well. Also tried setting it to Blue instead of No Color or Transparent - same results until I rebuilt/refreshed the value pointer.

Comment: Although this won't fix this issue. The correct way of setting "No Color" is to set the background to 'Nothing'  (no quotes)

Answer (score 0):

"Fixed"

I'm guessing it may have been an issue with SSRS caching or something. The code I have for the value is =LEFT(Fields!ACTNUMST.Value, 41). I deleted the LEFT functionality, ran the report and it ran correctly. I added the LEFT functionality back and it's still running correctly.

So, essentially, re-building the cell value pointer fixed the disappearing values issue. Beats me.

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio, you can delete the .data file it creates with your report to clear the cache and get a fresh result.

Comment: Cool thanks! I had not tried that, but will in the future. Great tip!

Comment: The frefresh bvutton on the SSRS tolbar will also do this. Not the browser refresh, I mean the refresh on the toolbar next to the page and zoom controls.

Comment: Thanks, Alan. I tried that refresh as well. Even completely closed and re-opened the report. It was displaying correctly in Report Builder but not the browser. Crazy glitch!